# How can I remove legends with 0 value Highcharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to remove from the legend list the series that have 0 value....I've tried

```
function(chart) {
  $.each(chart.series, function(i, series) {
      if (series.data[0].y === 0) { 
        series.hide();
      }
})};
```

but no luck, it hides all of the legend items...any help I would really appreciate...thanks!!

Comment: Hmmmm, could you possibly post a Fiddle?

Comment: Looks like you're iterating an object with keys and values, not elements ?

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate by each serie / points, check if is 0 value and remove legend group in SVG.

http://jsfiddle.net/hz2PN/

var flag = false;

```
        $.each(chart.series,function(i,serie){

            $.each(serie.data,function(j,data){

                if(data.y === 0){
                    flag=true;

                }
            });

            if(flag)
               serie.legendGroup.destroy();

        });
```